# Run shell script to take output of a file and convert it into Excel format

Tags: command-line, scripts, text-processing, convert

I have data in two different files called `test1.txt` and `test2.txt`, like:

```
ID : 1
Name: xxxx
Age: 33
Education: Mtech

ID: 2
Name: yyyy
Age: 22
Education: bsc
```

I want to print these lines using a shell script like this:

```
 1
 xxxx 
 33
 mtech
 2
 yyyy
 22
 bsc
```

and then I want to convert this output into Excel format. The format looks like below:

```
 ID Name    Age Education
 1  xxx     33  mtech
 2  yyy     22  bsc
```

How can I convert like this?

Comment: Is there a space after the first ID ?

Comment: no space after ID

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl + `ssconvert` (in the `gnumeric` package):

```
perl -F'\012' -00ane 'BEGIN {$, = ","; $\ = "\n"; print("ID,Name,Age,Education")} my @f; foreach(@F) {s/.*?: +//; push(@f, $_)} print(@f)' test1.txt test2.txt | ssconvert fd://0 output.xls
```

The Perl command reads `test1.txt` and `test2.txt` using blank lines as record separators and a newline characters as field separators; it prints the header (`Id,Name,Age,Education`) and for each record and for each field strips everything before the first character following the sequence of spaces following the first `:` character from each field and prints the record using commas as field separators and a newline character as record separators (i.e., it converts `test1.txt` and `test2.txt` to a CSV):

```
% cat test1.txt
ID : 1
Name: xxxx
Age: 33
Education: Mtech

ID: 2
Name: yyyy
Age: 22
Education: bsc
% cat test2.txt
ID : 3
Name: xxxx
Age: 33
Education: Mtech

ID: 4
Name: yyyy
Age: 22
Education: bsc
% perl -F'\012' -00ane 'BEGIN {$, = ","; $\ = "\n"; print("ID,Name,Age,Education")} my @f; foreach(@F) {s/.*?: +//; push(@f, $_)} print(@f)' test1.txt test2.txt
ID,Name,Age,Education
1,xxxx,33,Mtech
2,yyyy,22,bsc
3,xxxx,33,Mtech
4,yyyy,22,bsc
```

The `ssconvert` command reads from STDIN and converts the file to an Excel spreadsheet.

If installing `gnumeric` to obtain `ssconvert` is not an option, you could use just the Perl command and import the CSV into Excel / whatever:

```
perl -F'\012' -00ane 'BEGIN {$, = ","; $\ = "\n"; print("ID,Name,Age,Education")} my @f; foreach(@F) {s/.*?: +//; push(@f, $_)} print(@f)' test1.txt test2.txt >output.csv
```

Comment: convert into excel         ID Name    Age Education
                                       1  xxx       33  mtech
                                          2  yyy     22  bsc

Comment: add header ID age name Education and add output to excel.

Comment: @user476625 Added the header. I also forgot you were reading the input from multiple files, so I fixed that as well. Since you're new to the site, please have a read at [this](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) (You don't have to accept this answer, just letting you know that you're encouraged to accept one if you ever receive a satisfactory response).

Comment: Kos, cool solution ! +1

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==1{print $1,$3,$5,$7}
          {print $2,$4,$6,$8}' FS='[\\n:] *' OFS='\t' RS='' t*.txt > out.tsv

gnumeric out.tsv    #  excel or libreoffice, whatever
```

And as @kos presented we can ssconvert it the a world of diferent formats...

```
ssconvert out.tsv out.tex
ssconvert out.tsv out.pdf
```

Comment: This one is smooth, you didn't even have to rewrite the header! +1